# groupby multi-index to generate excel pivot sheet result, solution too ugly

Tags: python, pivot, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I am analyzing climate data with dates and temperatures, each day between 1950-2000 has an average temperature.
My intention is to calculate the 10 hottest years of the 50 years between 1950-2000 and visualize how many of the years fell into each of the 5 decades between 1950-2000. I thought, groupby with a multi-index (level 0: decade, level 1: year) would be the right approach. I had expected to get 50 years returned (length of df), with 5 decades as the corresponding level 0 index. But instead, I get 250 rows (5 decades x 50 years).
This is not what I had intended and it´s not what I need as the grouped dataframe´s decade 1950 includes years form all other decades, but with zero as temperature, same for the other decades
Why does groupby does that and how can I just get a length of 50 years?
I can create it in excel with decades and years as rows and average of temperature as values:
[image]

Hope you get what I mean, below is an example code I hope helps recreating the problem.

A (bad) solution is to remove all rows with zero values from the resulting series, but that´s not elegant nor good in case the average of a row is actually 0: **grouped = grouped[grouped != 0]**

Thanks!

```
# import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from numpy.random import randint
# create dataframe with dates as index and temperature on each date as column
cols = ['temperature']
dates = np.arange('1950', '2000', dtype='datetime64[D]')
len_dates = len(dates)
temp = randint(40, size=len_dates)
df = pd.DataFrame(temp, index=dates, columns=cols)

# extract year
df['year'] = df.index.year.astype('category')

# bin years into decades
cut_bins = np.arange(1950,2010,10).tolist()
cut_labels = [year for year in range(1950, 2000,10)]

df['decade'] = pd.cut(df['year'], bins=cut_bins, labels=cut_labels, include_lowest=True).astype('category')
df.head()

# groupby
grouped = df.groupby(['decade','year'])['temperature'].mean()
print('len(df): ', len(df))
print('len(grouped): ', len(grouped))
print('len(decade): ', len(df['decade'].unique()))
print('len(years): ', len(df['year'].unique()))
# resulting object has 250 rows yet only 50 years
print(grouped)

# remove needless rows from series
print(grouped = grouped[grouped != 0])

df.to_excel('groupedtest.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you asked pandas to sum all the possible groups including decade/year, so pandas will apply the cartesian product of all the possibilities (5 x 50 = 250).

I believe what you did above is mostly correct, the only step missing would be to sort the output. Here is my take on this task.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from numpy.random import randint
# create dataframe with dates as index and temperature on each date as column
cols = ['temperature']
dates = np.arange('1950', '2000', dtype='datetime64[D]')
len_dates = len(dates)
temp = randint(40, size=len_dates)
df = pd.DataFrame(temp, index=dates, columns=cols)

# extract year
df['year'] = df.index.year

idx = (
    df
    .groupby(["year"], as_index = False)  # group just by year
    .sum()  # find temp for the year, which from the question should be the sum
    .assign(
        decade = lambda df: df["year"].mod(100) - df["year"].mod(10)
    ) # compute the decade after grouping
    .sort_values("temperature", ascending = False)  # sort by highest temp
    .set_index("decade")
    .head(10) # get top 10
    .index
)
```

Once you have your top 10, you can just use a counter.

```py
from collections import Counter
Counter(idx)
```

Comment: Thank you, I have added a screenshot of an excel pivot so it becomes clearer what I want to create in python with the data I need for visualizations. Your explanation is helpful, but I need a different result. I also corrected the temperature calculation to .mean(), sum() was a mistake.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the desired output is. You claimed zero rows are needless however your temperature is a random number between 0 and 39. Hence in 18262 samples (i.e. length of dates) you almost certainly sample a zero.

Not sure what is wrong with a zero temperature either, some places are cold, unless the temperature is in Kelvin.

Comment: The excel output will display the average for each year, and next to the decade that is a _subtotal_, which should be the average of all yearly averages for that decade. Are you after the subtotal then?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I have temperatures between 0 and 39 degrees Celsius per day, ie 365 per year. I average those to an average temperature per year, so I end with temperatures for 50 different years. I am not interested in the subtotal.
Maybe an easier question is: how do I get to the same output like the excel screenshot with Pandas?